# Will there be a version of The Loop survey for users of the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion, feedback, the-loop

The newly announced [The Loop survey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/Z2YDMRD) asks for our satisfaction and thoughts about using Stack Overflow.

Will there be a version of this survey for users of the Stack Exchange network, or is the company currently just wanting feedback about Stack Overflow?

Comment: ...I may or may not have just taken it irregardless of it being SO centered, and just wrote SE in all my responses.

Comment: Yeah, this wording is confusing me quite a bit.  Is this survey supposed to be for the whole network, or just developers using the SO site?

Comment: @JMac it is exclusively addressed to users who participate actively (I imagine) on SO. Just see the survey, the questions are visible without answering any.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Loop survey is for Stack Overflow feedback only.  We'll be focusing on those responses first before moving to Stack Exchange.

Comment: Not sure if this is bad for good old "SO and SO above all" reasons or good because the rest of the network gets spared from this...thing. ;-)

Comment: We have to start somewhere and our resources allow us to do only one at a time.  For the time being, this is where we'll be.  I'd like to see this moved to SE though, I think lots of valuable feedback could be shared there too.

Comment: @Juan, is that feedback really valuable, given that anyone can "cheat" in their answers, and apparently can also take the survey several times using incognito mode? Seriously asking.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi When done that way the value will decrease (as you know). We're making a request for people to share with us what they think of SO and we're asking in good faith knowing that people can certainly cheat.  How people respond to the questions (and how often) is ultimately up to them.

Comment: Good faith is a two way street, Juan.  People aren't going to interact in good faith if they don't believe they've been treated in good faith.

Comment: Is MSE being "sunsetted" any time soon?

Comment: @VictorStafusa - That happened months ago

Comment: @fbueckert There are millions of users on SO - I doubt that a significant number of them are even vaguely aware of what’s going on here on Meta or care much about it. If it were otherwise, things would be different.

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways I don't doubt that that is part of the calculus in antagonizing the core userbase.  Problem is...you give disgruntled programmers a reason to break something, they're pretty creative in ensuring that thing is broken.  The honor system is...good, for values of, but like I said, good faith responses need good faith treatment.  Creating bots to flood the system with random data is likely a trivial task.

Comment: @Colleen, I've been seeing this argument for a while now. No offense, but yeah, a significant number of "them" are perfectly aware of what's going on here, and that's why SE's popular survey was directly to "them" in the first place. It is not only volume -- it is value. Users are asking why other sites were not part of the survey, and I understand that, but they should not dismiss SO as just *millions of [unconcerned] users* in the process -- there is a community there too :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi what do you consider a significant number? If it were truly a significant number of people who were disgruntled enough to try to purposefully thwart the feedback system and actually be able to taint the results, things would be different. I empathize with the frustration, but it’s not going to change anything.

Comment: @fbueckert I misunderstood your comment to be about less malicious methods of protesting, like individuals providing bad demographic data and putting a couple more feedback entries than one.

Comment: @Colleen, *if it were truly a significant number of people who were disgruntled enough to try to purposefully thwart the feedback system and actually taint the results, things would be different.* Yup, I truly would like a definitive answer to that. But my point was that the survey was targeted at SO in the first place for a reason, not the other way around. Since you are not a member, [this question on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391250/464709) might interest you -- it might be representative of something.

Comment: @JuanM "We're making a request for people to share with us what they think of SO...." I'd suggest that you modify the instrument itself to make that clear. I saw the banner pop up wherever it did, read the post, took the survey, and provided such answers as I could--all in good faith--thinking of myself as "purely" a network stackizen and just assumed that the questions were written by people insensitive to the SO/SE distinction. It never occurred to me that you didn't even want my feedback--I would have stayed away if I had understood it was fundamentally about SO.